# Past perfect/simple question in an example

Tags: grammaticality, past-tense, time, translation

Talking about the trip I did a few years ago:

> I have been there and  it was amazing. I had not seen a frozen sea until that time!

Did I use past perfect correctly or should I just say "I did not see .."? Also is the "until that time" ok?

Comment: A [frozen see](http://www.arcticnet.org/) is entirely possible :)

Comment: I corrected that typo :) Anyway I would need to know whether the tenses are correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The verb forms are fine, but, depending on context, *until then* might be more usual than *until that time*.

Comment: Thank you! Frankly speaking I do not know why I put the present perfect tense into the first part of that sentence and then past simple - "it was amazing", could you elaborate a bit on that?

Comment: ‘I have been there’ is present perfect because it describes a past event that has relevance at the time of speaking. ‘It was amazing’ is past tense because it describes what it was like at a particular time in the past.

Answer (score 2):

The usage is correct, but I would consider trying

> I had *never* seen a frozen sea *before*!